# Need help scanning a char* into a function with struct

Tags: c

I'm just starting to learn C in one of my college courses. We have gone over similar topics but not quite like what my professor is asking. I'm not great at all with pointers or structs so this assignment is getting frustrating, but I'm getting only one error in my last scanf saying "expected type char* but getting struct user**" and I cannot figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PEOPLE 10

struct user {
    int user_id;
    char* user_name;
};

void populate(struct user* users, int size);

void main() {
    struct user s1[PEOPLE], s2;
    populate(&s2, s1->user_id);
}

void populate(struct user* users, int size) {
    for(int i = 1; i < PEOPLE + 1; i++) {
        printf("Enter an ID of user %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &size);
        printf("Enter the name of user %d: ", i);
        scanf("%s", users);
    }
}
```

Here is the assignment:

Write a C programs that do the following:

Program defines a C struct, called user, that has two attributes

```
int user_id;
char* user_name;
```

Program declares an array of about 10 struct user variables and a function called populate() that takes as parameters a pointer to a struct user variable and an integer size. The populate() method will ask the user for an id and name to be assigned to each cell in the array of struct user variables until the array is full.
Hint: A header for this function might look like void populate (struct user* users, int size);

Here is the error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLUyo.png

Comment: Your code does not match the compiler warning you claim to have seen. Please post a [mre]. Also, accessing the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate is undefined behavior.

Comment: In `scanf("%s", users);`, the `%s` tells `scanf` to read characters from the input and assign them to elements of a character array, thus forming a string of characters (which it terminates with a null character). This operation needs a pointer to the first array element. But the parameter `users` passes a pointer to a `struct user`. That is not an array of characters, even though it contains an array of characters.

Comment: @EOF: The error message does match. And it is not a correct statement that accessing the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate is undefined behavior, for several reasons. (One of which is the C standard defines “access” to mean read or write, and obviously we can write a value to an object with a currently indeterminate value.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil have you tried compiling this? Are you *sure* that the error messages match? Have you *looked* at it? Did you *mean* to post this comment to me?

Comment: @EOF: Yes, I compiled it, and the message matches.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm afraid you should update your compiler, it is apparently broken because it cannot distinguish between a `struct user**` and a `struct user*`. Tragic.

Comment: @EOF: Okay, I missed the extra “*” on a tiny screen. Please be more detailed in your criticisms and do not leave people to guess why you think something does not match. Meanwhile, your statement about undefined behavior remains incorrect. Another reason is the rule about undefined behavior with automatic objects has a qualification that the address of the object must never have been taken. And a third reason is that the object must never have been initialized—if it subsequently became indeterminate, the rule does not apply.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So we've established that a) I was correct about the question being inconsistent and b) correct about the existence and type of undefined behavior. You decided to annoy me because a) you didn't check and b) you decided to require more precision from me in my descriptions of the problem. I can't help but feel you're being hypocritical here.

Comment: @EOF: Your statement about the mismatched message was technically true but not useful because it did not identify the problem. Do you think that helps anybody? How? Your statement about undefined behavior is false.

Answer (score 1):

In your second scanf statement, you're trying to capture a string argument with a struct variable. Your second scanf statement should be the following:

`scanf("%s", users-> user_name);`

You're also passing the wrong arguments to your function. The complete code is as given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PEOPLE 10

struct user {
    int user_id;
    char user_name[20];
};

void populate(struct user* users, int size);

void main() {
    struct user s1[PEOPLE];
    populate(s1, PEOPLE);
}

void populate(struct user users[], int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter an ID of user %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &users[i].user_id);
        printf("Enter the name of user %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", users[i].user_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would have never come to that conclusion. We have not learned it yet. While that did compile though, it now takes the first id and name, but that is all. It just prints the rest. (Enter id of 2: Enter name of: 2...... Enter name of 10). It does not ask me to enter any in from 2-10. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've edited the answer with complete solution. Please check

Comment: I see you changed some things with the char* and user*. I did not know I could do that for this assignment but it works! Thanks for your time again. Looks like I've still got so much to learn...

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for you. It can help others too.